# Div css animation on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have an button, which opens a "menu" with css animation.
It is like a fade / slide in animation:

Now I would like to realize this animation reverse (fade / slide out animation) onclick
But I don't know how I can realize it

https://jsfiddle.net/tafgd5mu/1/

```js
var isOpen = false;
$("#Widget").click(function() {
  // Close
  if (isOpen == true) {
    isOpen = false;
    $("#Widget").html('Open')
    // Open
  } else {
    isOpen = true;
    $('<div class="widget ">DIV</div>').insertAfter("#Widget");
    $("#Widget").html('Close')
  }
})
```

```css
@keyframes widget-slide-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 40;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 80;
  }
}

.widget {
  width: 450px;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  top: initial;
  background-color: #eef0f4;
  flex-direction: column;
  animation: widget-slide-in 0.25s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, bottom 0.25s ease-in-out;
  left: unset !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}

.button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  top: initial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 12px 23px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
  background-color: #7ebd0b;
  font-family: 'Nunito', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  will-change: auto;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: unset !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}

.button>svg {
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Widget" class="button">Open</button>
```

Comment: It's very hard to give you a good answer without seeing any code.

Comment: I had problems with the implemantion of jsfiddle. Please click on the link to see the complete code. https://jsfiddle.net/tafgd5mu/1/

Comment: Well for one, you need to only create the div once.

Comment: and than ? How will this fade out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is by using Jquery slideToggle()

This method toggles between slideUp() and slideDown() for the selected elements as mentioned in the documentation.

https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidetoggle.asp

Comment: Yeah the actual documentation is the best explained. Sorry I forgot to provide the actual jquery documentation link .

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your CSS, you can see that you have keyframes for your animation:

```
@keyframes widget-slide-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 40; }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 80; } 
}
```

If you further inspect your code, you can also see that this animation is used on your `Widget` class. If you create a new set of keyframes, and switch the values in the `from` and `to` parameters, you will have the animation that you need, if I understand your question correctly.

You could then call this `widget-slide-out` for example, and add this animation to your element, onClick, if `isOpen == true` as per. your jQuery code.

I would however, as the commenter above suggested, only add the div element once or at least, remove it again.

You could also look into using the `.slideToggle()` functionality that jQuery has, since it could be used in this case, in my opinion.

https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/